# How to use if else properly

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm using the redux framework for my wordrpess site to create a button option in the backend.

When an user input a button title & link, it'll create a button automatically in the frontend  in a selected place. The problem is, if the fields are blank, I mean no title or links are inserted by the user, the button style still shows in the front end without any text or link (see attached screenshot).

I know I can use `if else` condition, so when only users input something in the field, the button shows, otherwise nothing will be seen. I don't know how to do it, as I'm not a pro.

Here is my code for the button at this moment:

```
<div class="imd-btn">
    <a href="<?php echo $redux_imd['project-btn-link']; ?>"><?php echo $redux_imd['project-btn-text']; ?></a>
</div>
```

[image: here is the screenshot for button styles in front end]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values are left blank, the `imd-btn` dissappears and the button will not appear in the page.

```
<?php 

if(($redux_imd['project-btn-link']!='') && ($redux_imd['project-btn-text']!='')){?>

<div class="imd-btn">
    <a href="<?php echo $redux_imd['project-btn-link']; ?>"><?php echo $redux_imd['project-btn-text']; ?></a>
</div>


<?php
}


?>
```

Comment: I'd rather use `<?php if(...): ?> html <?php endif; ?>` while mixing php and html.

Comment: great! thank you so much for your help. I ll select it as a correct answer in 8 minutes(it doesn't let me do it right now). :)